# CloudPages development with new Content Builder functionality

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, content-builder

When I add html block in CloudPage and add html tags in that particular html block I.e. `<html>` `<body>` `<style>` and when I click on save or publish that cloudpage those html tags got disappeared,  is that known issue or am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if you would click the "Code View" button to see the HTML code of the CloudPage, you would find that `<html>` and `<body>` tags are already there and those could be mentioned only once on the page, otherwise browsers would have difficulties to render the page.

As for the `<style>` tag, it is actually there, but the HTML block is invisible and it contains only `<style>` and `</style>` tags, since `<html>` and `<body>` got automatically deleted.